# how do you change the width and heigth for popover in material ?

Tags: material-ui, popover

I am trying to modify the width and height  on popover  material ui but nothing ? please help thanks

```
                                      open={open}
                                      anchorEl={anchorEl}
                                      className={{
                                            height: '300px',
                                            width: '250px'
                                      }}
                                      anchorOrigin={{
                                        vertical: 'top',
                                        horizontal:'left',
                                      }}
                                      transformOrigin={{
                                        vertical: 'top',
                                        horizontal: 'right',
                                      }}
                                      disableRestoreFocus
                                    >
```

Comment: [FAQ on how to question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 23):

Use the PaperProps property of Popover:

```
      <Popover
        id={id}
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        onClose={handleClose}
        value={value}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: 'top',
          horizontal: 'center',
        }}
        transformOrigin={{
          vertical: 'top',
          horizontal: 'center',
        }}
        PaperProps={{
          style: { width: '100%' },
        }}
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way of doing that is to stretch the content inside the Popover, because it's width is calculated automatically.

```
<Popover>
  <div 
    style={{ 
      width: '300px', 
      height: '200px'
    }}
  >
    Some inside content
  </div>
</Popover>
```

And that will stretch Popover itself to desired size.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by changing slotProps in MUi. Here you can see an example below:

```
<Popover
  {...otherProps}
  slotProps={{
    paper: {
      sx(theme) {
        return {
          [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
            width: "100%",
            height: "150px",
          },
        };
      },
    },
  }}
>
  <Typography>Awesome popover of mui</Typography>
</Popover>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have the className equal to css, this will not work. You can either change the className to style, and it should work or you're going to have to add a const variable and hook it into the withStyle HOC. Then add the height and width to that const, and then call the class you made in that to the className.

All these examples are on the material-ui site. https://material-ui-next.com/getting-started/faq/  I've found extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change style of this class name on your css file `.MuiPaper-elevation8` like :

```
.MuiPaper-elevation8{
width: 300px;
height: 150px;
}
```